# Can someone explain why this mysql query takes forever to execute? Its like it's stuck in a loop with no results returned

Tags: sql, mysql

Can someone please explain why this mysql query takes forever to execute? Its like it's stuck in a loop with no results returned.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obnkv.jpg)

```
SELECT m.title
FROM movies m
JOIN movie_starredin c ON m.ratingkey = c.movieid
WHERE c.actorid IN ( 
    SELECT id 
    FROM movie_actors 
    WHERE name = 'Harrison Ford'
);
```

Comment: How many records are there in these tables?

Comment: I posted a screenshot

Comment: There are 159,973 records in movie_actors and 344,503 records in movie_starredin

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/). Use [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) and [`EXPLAIN ANLYZE`](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-explain-analyze/) to view query plan/execution details. Your junction table (`movie_starredin`) needs indexing in both directions - `(movieid, actorid)` and `(actorid, movieid)`, with one of them probably being the PK. An index on `movie_actors.name` will remove the need for the full table scan on `movie_actors`.

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks for the clarification. Will get to reading up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could "Debug" your query execution time by seperate it into smaller query:

1 . Run this and check exec time:

```
SELECT id 
FROM movie_actors 
WHERE name = 'Harrison Ford'
```

2 . Run this and check exec time:

```
SELECT *
FROM movie_starredin
WHERE actorid IN ( 
    SELECT id 
    FROM movie_actors 
    WHERE name = 'Harrison Ford'
);
```

3 . Run this and check exec time, with xxxxx is a value of `movie_starredin.actorid`:

```
SELECT m.title
FROM movies m
JOIN movie_starredin c ON m.ratingkey = c.movieid
WHERE c.actorid = xxxxx;
```

Each step check if exec time too long/ slow. Then use index to reduce exec time of sql select (search google for this). But consider the tradeoff that is design of the table you want to add index because index could slow down insert, update action to table with large number (millions) of records.

Comment: 1 .

Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0257 seconds.) 
SELECT id FROM movie_actors WHERE name = 'Harrison Ford';

id
5975

2 .

Was stil a no go! No execution.

3 .

Showing rows 0 - 24 (50 total, Query took 0.1416 seconds.)
SELECT m.title FROM movies m JOIN movie_starredin c ON m.ratingkey = c.movieid WHERE c.actorid = 5975; 

title 
The Age of Adaline
Air Force One
American Graffiti
Apocalypse Now
Blade Runner
Blade Runner 2049
The Call of the Wild
Clear and Present Danger
The Conversation
Cowboys & Aliens

Comment: Finaly Executed # 2. Showing rows 0 - 49 (50 total, Query took 4.9658 seconds.)
SELECT * FROM movie_starredin WHERE actorid IN( SELECT id FROM movie_actors WHERE name = 'Harrison Ford' );  I added indexes but it still took a little while.

Comment: and also finaly excecuted my original query Showing rows 0 - 24 (50 total, Query took 45.3798 seconds.)
SELECT m.title FROM movies m JOIN movie_starredin c ON m.ratingkey = c.movieid WHERE c.actorid IN ( SELECT id FROM movie_actors WHERE name = 'Harrison Ford' ); but took way longer. but got the same results as your #3 query. Not sure if there is anything more to be done that can remedy the execution times?

Comment: Thank you! I've learned that forming a better query statement makes for a much faster execution time.

Comment: Sorry, SQL does not work that way. The path could change as the steps are added/removed.

Answer (score 0):

> please explain why this mysql query takes forever to execute

We cannot answer this directly, as you have not included the DDL (`SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;`) for your tables or the [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) output for your example query, but I think it is reasonable to assume that it is likely due to a lack of appropriate indices.

[`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) is often the first port of call when wanting to understand the performance of a query. [8.8.2 EXPLAIN Output Format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html) has lots of details on the output.

#### Test schema

This is my test schema with data imported from [IMDb](https://developer.imdb.com/non-commercial-datasets/):

```sql
CREATE DATABASE `imdb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
USE `imdb`;

CREATE TABLE `title_basics` (
  `tconst` int unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `titleType` enum('short','movie','tvSeries','tvShort','tvMovie','tvEpisode','tvMiniSeries','tvSpecial','video','videoGame','tvPilot'),
  `primaryTitle` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `originalTitle` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `isAdult` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `startYear` smallint unsigned,
  `endYear` smallint unsigned,
  `runtimeMinutes` smallint unsigned,
  `genres` varchar(255)
);
-- Rows: 9,438,577  Data_length: 0.88GB

CREATE TABLE `name_basics` (
  `nconst` int unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `primaryName` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `birthYear` smallint unsigned,
  `deathYear` smallint unsigned,
  `primaryProfession` varchar(80),
  `knownForTitles` varchar(80)
);
-- Rows: 13,042,955 Data_length: 0.89GB

CREATE TABLE `title_principals` (
  `tconst` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ordering` smallint unsigned,
  `nconst` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category` enum('self','director','cinematographer','composer','producer','editor','actor','actress','writer','production_designer','archive_footage','archive_sound'),
  `job` varchar(1024),
  `characters` varchar(1024)
);
-- Rows: 57,378,319 Data_length: 3.06GB
```

For these tests, the entire dataset was preloaded into the [buffer pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html).

#### Base query

This is my version of your query, given my slightly different schema (returns 603 rows):

```sql
SELECT m.primaryTitle
FROM title_basics m
JOIN title_principals c ON m.tconst = c.tconst
WHERE c.nconst IN (
    SELECT nconst
    FROM name_basics
    WHERE primaryName = 'Harrison Ford'
);
```

Executing this query without any additional indices, I get the following execution plan:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | name_basics | ALL | PRIMARY |  |  |  | 13119941 | 0.00 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | c | ALL |  |  |  |  | 57598197 | 0.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |
| 1 | SIMPLE | m | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | imdb.c.tconst | 1 | 100.00 |  |

Timing: 29.750 sec / 6.141 sec

Rows accessed: 70,421,877 (quite a lot)

This is bad news, as we have two full table scans (`ALL` in the type column) and they are of large tables (~13M & ~57M rows).

#### Adding an index on `primaryName`

```sql
ALTER TABLE `imdb`.`name_basics`
    ADD INDEX `idx_name` (`primaryName`);
```

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | name_basics | ref | PRIMARY,idx_name | idx_name | 482 | const | 4 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | c | ALL |  |  |  |  | 57598197 | 0.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |
| 1 | SIMPLE | m | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | imdb.c.tconst | 1 | 100.00 |  |

Timing: 25.438 sec / 6.328 sec

Rows accessed: 57,378,926 (still a lot)

Here we can see a dramatic improvement in the access of `name_basics`, instead of the full table scan seen in the first query, we are now using the index to access an estimated 4 rows (instead of ~13M), and it is not having to access the clustered index (the actual table data), as everything that is needed is in the secondary index ([`Using index`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#:%7E:text=Using%20index%20(JSON%20property%3A%20using_index)) in Extra column). Unfortunately, this is only a small improvement for the overall execution time as we are still having to scan the ~57M rows in `title_principals`.

#### Adding indices for FKs

A common approach is just to index the foreign keys, so let's add single column indices for the FKs on `title_principals`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `imdb`.`title_principals`
    ADD INDEX `idx_tconst` (`tconst`),
    ADD INDEX `idx_nconst` (`nconst`);
```

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | name_basics | ref | PRIMARY,idx_name | idx_name | 482 | const | 4 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | c | ref | idx_tconst,idx_nconst | idx_nconst | 4 | imdb.name_basics.nconst | 13 | 100.00 |  |
| 1 | SIMPLE | m | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | imdb.c.tconst | 1 | 100.00 |  |

Timing: 0.016 sec / 0.000 sec

Rows accessed: 1,267 (that's better)

Here we can see we have got rid of the full table scan for `title_principals` and instead of having to scan ~57M rows, it is now estimating 13 rows.

#### Using composite indices for the junction table

We can take this a step further by adding composite indices instead:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `imdb`.`title_principals`
    DROP INDEX `idx_tconst` (`tconst`),
    DROP INDEX `idx_nconst` (`nconst`),
    ADD INDEX `idx_tconst_nconst` (`tconst`, `nconst`),
    ADD INDEX `idx_nconst_tconst` (`nconst`, `tconst`);
```

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | name_basics | ref | PRIMARY,idx_name | idx_name | 482 | const | 4 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | c | ref | idx_tconst_nconst,idx_nconst_tconst | idx_nconst_tconst | 4 | imdb.name_basics.nconst | 10 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | m | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | imdb.c.tconst | 1 | 100.00 |  |

Timing: 0.016 sec / 0.000 sec

Rows accessed: 1,267

The benefit here is less obvious, but it is still there. If you look at the `Extra` column, we now have [`Using index`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#:%7E:text=Using%20index%20(JSON%20property%3A%20using_index)) meaning -

> The column information is retrieved from the table using only information in the index tree without having to do an additional seek to read the actual row.

When checking the server-side execution time, averaged over 10 runs each, I got 0.007s (single column) and 0.003s (composite).

This has ended up being much longer than I intended, but I hope it proves useful to someone.